# Connection to http://192.168.183.2 refused

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to execute "insert" sql query to mysql from my android app and i get a connection refused error.
My database is localhost, 192.168.188.2 is my ip adress, i have tried to replace the adresse with localhost or 127.0.0.1 but it doesnt work.

Is someone can help me with this it would be cool :)

here is the java code :

```
private void setClient(String actifs[], int age, String sexe){

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", Integer.toString(age)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sexe",sexe));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p1",actifs[0]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p2",actifs[1]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p3",actifs[2]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p4",actifs[3]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p5",actifs[4]));

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.188.1/MyLab/AppBdd.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

and Php file :

```html
  require_once ("res.php");
  
 $pdo = PdoGsb::getPdoGsb();
 
  $nom = "leo";
  $prenom = "lucie";
  $sexe = $_REQUEST['sexe'];
  $age = $_REQUEST['age']
  $ville = "genas";
  $mail = "test";
  $max  = $_REQUEST['p1'];
  $max2  = $_REQUEST['p2'];
  $max3  = $_REQUEST['p3'];
  $max4  = $_REQUEST['p4'];
  $max5  = $_REQUEST['p5'];

$pdo->setClient($nom, $prenom, $sexe, $age, $ville, $mail, $max, $max2, $max3, $max4, $max5);
```

Pdo object :

```html
<?php 

class PdoGsb{  
       
  private static $serveur='mysql:host=localhost';
  private static $bdd='dbname=testdepeau';     
       private static $user='root';
  private static $mdp='';
  private static $monPdo;
  private static $monPdoGsb=null;

  
 private function __construct(){
     PdoGsb::$monPdo = new PDO(PdoGsb::$serveur.';'.PdoGsb::$bdd, PdoGsb::$user, PdoGsb::$mdp); 
  PdoGsb::$monPdo->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
  PdoGsb::$monPdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }
 public function _destruct(){
  PdoGsb::$monPdo = null;
 }

 public  static function getPdoGsb(){
  if(PdoGsb::$monPdoGsb==null){
   PdoGsb::$monPdoGsb= new PdoGsb();
  }
  return PdoGsb::$monPdoGsb;  
 }
 
 public function setClient($nom, $prenom, $sexe, $age, $ville, $mail, $max, $max2, $max3, $max4, $max5){
  $req="INSERT INTO client (nom, prenom, sexe, age, ville, email, pa1, pa2, pa3, pa4, pa5)
   VALUES
   ('$nom', '$prenom', '$sexe', '$age', '$ville', '$mail', '$max', '$max2', '$max3', '$max4', '$max5');";
   $res2= PdoGsb::$monPdo->exec($req);

 }
 
}
?>
```

Comment: Try with `10.0.2.2`. Info: http://blogs.adobe.com/jtalbot/2010/12/07/accessing-localhost-from-the-android-emulator/

Comment: Are you actually running a webserver on that IP? And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and your sql is full of syntax errors.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: What's this: `$res2= exec($req);`? Do you mean to make a system call? And I don't see `$req` being defined anywhere...

Comment: I edited all @MagnusEriksson sorry for the poor code but my problem was on the connection refused i didnt code properly the sql part.

Comment: You're still wide open to SQL Injections, though. Since you're working with PDO, you should protect yourself by using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Anyway, what happens if you access the page from a browser on the same machine or from another machine on the same network? Do you still get "connection refused"? Is the server open and accessible on the network at all?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The server is localhost, and if i access the page from a browser and i replace the "request[''"] by variable the php code works and the data are correctly inserted in my db